# Sending mail with delivery receipt?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use a function that sends emails to some users.

I use the following code to send delivery notification failure messages to the sender email

when a message fails to reach the user.

I use the following code.

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage messagetest = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
messagetest.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", txtFrom.Text);
```

now I want to enable the sender to receive a Delivered receipt message when the mail arrives successfully.

how can this be done ?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MailMessage has a [`DeliveryNotificationOptions` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.deliverynotificationoptions.aspx), set it like this:

```
messagetest .DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
```

[There are a few other options as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.deliverynotificationoptions.aspx) if you need them.

Comment: Thanks Nick

But i want to achieve this with the System.Web.Mail.MailMessage class. is this feasible ?

Comment: @Mina - I'm not sure, the entire `System.Web.Mail` namespace is deprecated now...let me see what I can find.

Comment: @Mina - Is there a reason for not moving to System.Net.Mail?  it should be a fairly painless upgrade, just curious.

Comment: I have to use it cause the server requires authentication which cannpt be achieved by the smtp client class as the server requires Base64 authentication.